# How can I ask for the same input again when there was incorrect input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
players = input("How many players?")
if players == "1":
    p1 +=1
elif players == "2":
    p2 +=1
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
    players = input("How many players?")
```

How can I get the else to repeat when an invalid input is entered?

Answer (score 6):

Use an infinite loop and `break` out when you have your input:

```
while True:
    players = input("How many players?")
    if players == "1":
        p1 += 1
        break
    elif players == "2":
        p2 += 1
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, please pick 1 or 2. Let's try again")
```